# how to call javascript function using widgets in django form

Tags: django

Hi i want to call js function when a field in form is clicked or typed in I have used this code:

class ProviderSugForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = ProviderSug
    fields = ['due_date', 'price', 'description', 'discount']
    widgets = {
        'due_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
        'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'onclick': 'numberWithCommas()'}),
    }
```

but the js function is gray in my html template and not working

Comment: try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264701/jquery-function-not-defined-with-onclick-attribute-set-inside-django-forms-form)

Comment: Where is this function defined ?

Comment: in my html code.just my function requires an number input?how should pass that?

Answer (score -1):

use a comma just after the function

```
class Meta:
model = ProviderSug
fields = ['due_date', 'price', 'description', 'discount']
widgets = {
    'due_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
    'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'onclick': 'numberWithCommas()',}),
}
```